# How does one create a Rails app with a module name not derived from the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running `rails new APP_PATH [options]`, I don't see an option for specifying a custom module name which isn't derived from the basename of `APP_PATH`.

For example, if I want my application to use the module `FooApp`, and be in the path `./foo_app_rails`, I currently do the following (in a Bash shell):

```
$ rails new ./foo_app
$ mv ./foo_app ./foo_app_rails
```

Is there an option to do something like this...

```
# --module MODULE option overrides default module name of FooAppRails
$ rails new ./foo_app_rails --module FooApp
```

I visually scanned the help text for an option that does this, and didn't see anything, and grepping for words that might be relevant didn't reveal an answer.

```
$ rails new --help | grep -i name
      [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]            # Skip namespace (affects only isolated applications)
$ rails new --help | grep -i class
$ rails new --help | grep -i module
$ rails new --help | grep -i custom
$ rails new --help | grep -i path
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                        # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--rc=RC]                                            # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
```

I don't NEED this option.  Mostly I was surprised it didn't exist :)

Comment: You'll probably get more interest regarding your question if your title was a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks, I nerfed an edit.  Is this title more clear? => `How does one create a Rails app with a module name not derived from the path?`